# How to make many transactions in one transaction to pay less gas

Tags: web3js, nodejs

Web3.js 
 
Good afternoon, can you please tell me how I can make several transactions from different wallets to one wallet?

We have conditionally realized system of deposit and main wallet. When the amount on the exchange reaches **0.2 ETH** we transfer all funds from all wallets to the main wallet.

Is there any possibility to pay gas less than that for each transaction?

Comment: If you are using EOA then it isn't possible, yet. If you use you own contract wallet you could program anything you want like batching.